# Drupal Multi-Site Migration

Tags: drupal

I was looking to migrate two Drupal sites. I think it is a multi-site setup, but I am not absolutely sure about that. The two sites have their own databases but the second site is sharing the first site's database as well. Again, I am not exactly sure how it is all set up, and that is why I need help.

The first site collects leads. It has a form which the user fills out. Then the data is saved on the current site. This is done using a custom Module's form.

The second site tracks the leads. This site is referencing its own database as well as the database of the main site, hence it is sharing the leads table from the first site's database.

I need help migrating these two sites to a new server and to keep the multisite setup in tact so the two sites still communicate with each other at the end.

So, I was looking for some help in understanding multi-site setups. I am a Drupal developer myself, but have no experience doing multi sites.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things to look at:

1. Look at the apache configuration. In a multi site environment apache must be set up to point to the same document root for multiple domain names. Make sure you understand how this is done on the current system.
2. You have a settings.php for every site. Simply make sure you do set the right DB access information for every site.

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to read about how you'd do a new multi-site setup to understand what they did: http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

If you're just moving them to a new server, it shouldn't be too difficult. The trick to keeping it simple it to just match the database setup (database name, user name, password).

The steps are roughly:

- Dump the database(s) to .sql files.
- Copy everything (database dumps, Drupal's code, the sites files directory, etc) over to the new host.
- Configure the vhosts on the new server.
- Create the database(s) and add the users, you can get the credentials the site is currently using from the settings.php files (as BetaRide notes).
- Restore the database dump(s) to the appropriate locations.
- Test that the site matches up to the old one.

Then it's just a matter of dumping the databases to .sql files and copying everything (Drupal's code and the sites files directory) over to the new server.

Answer (score 0):

Two things that will help you figure out multi site settings

- Folder Structure
- Settings.php
  Suppose 2 sites are named as example.com and example.com/fr 
  Then in sites DIR you will find similar named folders example.com and example.com.fr
  You need to back up these.

next in settings.php look for a variable $db_prefix and $db_url.
db_url tells you the main DB name that site is referring to and if db_prefix is defined it will tell you another DB Name where some of the tables are being referred to.
back up all those db's mentioned in settings.php file as well.
You have all required back ups now , can do a migrate now.